# How to make UVM build_phase cooperate with build function in SVunit

Tags: unit-testing, system-verilog, uvm

I'm new to UVM and SVunit. As i'm trying to write a unit test for scoreboard, I found that if the `uvm_analysis_imp` port is instantiated in build phase of scoreboard and if we connect it to a `uvm_analysis_port`  in build function of scoreboard_unit_test module, there will be a null handle problem. It seems that the build phase of scoreboard is executed later than the build() function inside module. If I put the instatiation of the  `uvm_analysis_imp` into constructor of scoreboard, there will be no problem. But we cannot simply change the UUT to fit our test right? If I still want to keep every instatiation inside build phase, what can i do with this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't you be _connecting_ the `uvm_analysis_imp` to the `uvm_analysis_port` in the _connect_ phase (which is guaranteed too occur after the build phase)?

Comment: Usually one instantiates(creates object) of a port/imp in build_phase (top-down phase). And connect it in connect_phase (bottom-up phase).

Comment: Thanks for answering. But here what i meant is to use SVunit to test the component. It uses an extra module to connect to the component and manually input some parameters to see whether the single component can work properly. Inside the testing module,  there's some predefined functions. One of them is the build function which plays the similar role as build_phase in uvm_component. But there's no connect phase inside the module. So i think the connection should also be done inside the build function or setup function. But both these functions are exucuted before the build_phase of component.

Comment: In which case, I can't help you, I'm afraid.

Comment: This might help http://www.agilesoc.com/open-source-projects/svunit/svunit-user-guide/#Special_Considerations_for_Unit_Testing_UVM_Components

Comment: `build_phase` in uvm is top down phase. So can you please point the location of `uvm_analysis_port` and `uvm_analysis_imp` in terms of hierarchy from top module (if you are using uvm, then it would be `uvm_test_top`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to instantiate the TLM ports in SV to transfer data from SVunit to UVM and also make syncrhonisation. My belive is that you cannot use uvm_analysis_imp port in SVunit, becuase SVunit just dont know what object is this.
I think you need to make the synchronisation between SVunit and UVM code in run_phase of UVM.
So you can define either some event to make their synchronisation, than use another function to transfer data. Or you can user mailbox there